# "budget" vs "budgeting" tags

Tags: discussion, tags

We have tags for both [budget](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/budget) and [budgeting](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/budgeting).  To me, these look identical.  Currently, there are 123 questions tagged "budget" and only 9 questions tagged "budgeting".  6 of these questions are tagged with both tags.

In my opinion, we don't need both tags.  Any preference as to which one should be kept?

If I don't get any strong opinions one way or the other in the next several days, I'll go ahead and edit the 9 "budgeting" questions and tag them all "budget".

Comment: agreed. really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefer budget also. However, couldn't we just set up a tag synonym?

Comment: We certainly could set up a tag synonym.  But with only 9 questions to edit, it is not much work to just edit the questions.  Also, I think it would be less confusing if the "budgeting" tag simply disappears from the tag list, rather than have two tags showing up when you type "budget" into the tag search (even if one is a synonym of the other).

Comment: @BenMiller A tag synonym will also prevent the unwanted variant from recurring.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea That's true. It really doesn't matter to me. I don't have the synonym power, but if a mod wants to set up a synonym, go for it.

Comment: I'd also be happy with a synonym

Comment: Answer accepted.  I didn't see any disagreement.  Would you mind setting up the tag synonym for us?

Comment: I think Ganesh already did a few weeks ago.

Comment: @JohnFx No, I don't think he did.  There are still [9 questions tagged "budgeting"](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/budgeting).

Comment: @BenMiller Looks like Dheer proposed one on Dec 1st, and I've now approved it: http://money.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms - let me know if anything seems wrong or anything more is needed.